# Regex for 6 character text with/without spaces in between

Tags: python, regex

Hi I am looking for a regex that will recognize this patterns:

The first letters always begin with a character `R/L/F` etc, and there's always `5` numbers following it.

I am having problem with coding the regex where there is a space or multiple spaces in between.

```
R20209
R4 01 08
R5 0801
```

Also, sometimes the zero will be recognize as `o` so instead of `R20209` it will be `R2o2o9`. Is there a way to account for this too?

Thanks

Edited:
Thanks zr0gravity7, I mean Letter followed by '5' digits number instead of '4' digits number

Comment: Did you mean "there's always **5** numbers following it."?

Comment: show some code and make an example of in input with desired output, not much clear

Comment: How can ```o``` be recognised as ```0``` ? That's strange.

Comment: @Ram probably some OCR

Comment: Are there any spaces in between those 5 numbers. If so, how many ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RegEx-only solution:**

```
^[A-Z](?:[\doO] ?){4}[\doO]$
```

This will match an uppercase letter followed by exactly four occurrences of a digit (or "o"/"O") trailed by an optional space, then a final occurrence of a digit (or "o"/"O"), this time without a trailing space. It matches the entire string due to the beginning and end anchors.

*Try it out*: https://regex101.com/r/5kmXEe/1

To force the first character to be a specific letter, you can replace the `[A-Z]` with for example `[RLF]`.

To allow for any number of spaces between the digits, you can use the Kleene star to greedily match more spaces:

```
^[A-Z](?:[\doO] *){4}[\doO]$
```

Comment: what if the RLF might also be a small letter rlf

Comment: Simply add them to the character class! So `[RLFrlf]` should work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This answer is correct. however, for some reason i need to remove the '^' in the beginning and '$' at the end? Do you know why? The final regex is this: '[RLFrlf](?:[\doO] *){4}[\doO]'

Comment: The caret and dollar sign are beginning and end anchors, respectively. When they are both present like this at the extremes of the pattern, they force the pattern to match the entire string. For example, the pattern `foo` will match the string `"food"` (namely the first three characters), however, the pattern `^foo$` will not match the string `"food"`, because it does not match the entire string. In your case, I added the anchors with the assumption that the pattern would be matched once per string. If your are trying to find the pattern multiple times in the string, then you would drop them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this.

- `[RLF]` - Matches Either of R, L, F.
- `\s*` - Matches zero or more spaces.
- `[\do]` - Matches either a digit or letter `o`.
- `re.I` - Ignores letter case. Matches both uppercase and lowercase.

```
import re

s = '''R20209 R4 01  08 R5 08 01 F2 3 4 5 Af R4567 LL45 67 R 2o2o 9 R 3070 L 5 66 6 r34567 L3O45O'''
f = re.findall(r'\b[RLF]\s*[\do]\s*[\do]\s*[\do]\s*[\do]\s*[\do]',s,re.I)

print(f)
```

```
['R20209', 'R4 01  08', 'R5 08 01', 'R 2o2o 9',  'r34567', 'L3O45O']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better off eliminating the spaces from the string and changing `o` and `O` to `0`.

```
import re
def fun(str):
    str_formatted = str.replace(' ','').replace('o', '0').replace('O', '0')
    return re.match('[RLF]\d{5}', str_formatted)[0]

for i in ['R20209', 'R4 o1 08', 'R5 O8o1']:
    print(fun(i))
```